# generic method to get variable with class extension

Tags: java, generics

I try to build a generic method but I dont know how to convert it and if it is possible in Java

This is original method

```
public List<PcsTTR> obtainAllPcsTttrRecords() throws Exception {

    try {
        TypedQuery<PcsTTR> pQuery = em.createNamedQuery("PcsTTR.findAll", PcsTTR.class);
        return pQuery.getResultList();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        throw new Exception("database error ", t);
    }

}
```

I used factory pattern

```
public <T> List<T> obtainAllRecords(String tableName) throws Exception {

    // if tableName = PcsTTR Im getting PcsTtr object
    myEntity tableObj = myEntityFactory.getTableObj(tableName); 

    String tableObjName = table.getClass().getSimpleName();
    try {
        TypedQuery<T> pQuery = em.createNamedQuery(tableObjName+".findAll", ??????);
        return pQuery.getResultList();

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        throw new Exception("database error " + tableNamee + " !" + t);
    }

}
```

I dont know what to put instead of "???"

Comment: `table.getClass()`

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can use is [TypeToken](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html) which is part of the Gson artifact.

```java
            TypedQuery<T> pQuery = em.createNamedQuery(tableObjName+".findAll", new TypeToken<T>() {}.getRawType());
```

Comment: is there any solution with plain java 8?

Comment: You could forcefully pass Class<T> which would solve it, but could be redundant.

Comment: TypedQuery<T> pQuery = em.createNamedQuery(tableNamee+".findAll", Class <T> ); that doesnt work :(  syntax error on token ">"

Comment: Yeah thats because you need to provide a name for that parameter. i.e; `Class<T> typeClass`

Comment: but how to get typeClass dynamic from tableObj ?

Comment: You can create an in-house method to get the parameterized type of T. Look into how its done here if you want. https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.java